How to properly set an error handler action for a specific controller?
For the need of my application, I have a controller that needs to be on a separate error handler. To do that I set the error handler in the init method of my controller by doing
Yii:$app->errorHandler->errorAction = 'controller/action'.
I trigger an exception and it is caught but by default error handler. In my web.php I have the global error handler configured like this.
'errorHandler' => ['errorAction' => 'some_other_controller/some_action' ]

I am out of ideas as to why my error action is not triggered.

It looks like you can call your error handler from the controller action as it's described here https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/custom-error-handler/85226/4

The init() method of your controller is executed before the action is called. If an exception is thrown in the init() method, it will be caught by the default error handler. Consider moving your error handling logic to a different method or action or you can try override the application’s error handler with the module’s one. In your module configuration, set the error handler:
/** @var ErrorHandler $handler */
$handler = $this->get('errorHandler');
Yii::$app->set('errorHandler', $handler);
$handler->register();

